# Picking the first element using xpath in capybara

Tags: html, xpath, ambiguity

I have the following line of code

```
link = find(:xpath, "//div[@id='tree']//a[contains(.,'#{peril}')]")
```

Above step yields in two elements. How do I pick the first one.

I am getting a Ambiguous match found 2 elements matching xpath. Here is the HTML
"
   ShipCase_US_MortalityRatingGroup_Life   Portfolio result   Earthquake   Infectious Disease"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to surround the entire XPath in parentheses and add the `[1]` after it.

```
(//div[@id='tree']//a[contains(.,'#{peril}')])[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`find(".active", match: :first).click`

this solution uses Capybara's (quite important) waiting capabilities

Comment: This solution is cleaner and more understandable for everyone who reads the tests 